Coloring charts
first of all, sorry for my English, I don't know if I can explain what I would like to do...
I have this: https://jsfiddle.net/rp6b40ak/
            plotOptions: {
                areaspline: {
                    zones: [
                        {
                            value: -99.9,
                            color: '#be00be'
                        },
                        {
                            value: -40.0,
                            color: '#dc00dc'
                        },
                        {
                            value: -30.9,
                            color: '#e600ff'
                        }, etc.

I would like to make the chart area have the same color as the line above it. Currently, these are "stairs". If the value of 20 degrees is yellow, I would like the entire graph to be yellow at that point, green at 9 degrees, and so on.
Second thing, I would like the chart to gradually lose its opacity, the further down, the lower the opacity, like here: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/line-time-series
like the weather on MSN.
I even tried to use AI, but without success, please help.


To color the space below the line in the line color, you should use zones for the xAxis. So you need to change the zoneAxis option to 'x' and change the values in the zones array. To get the gradient, you should use the fillColor property.

Docs: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.areaspline.zoneAxis
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.areaspline.zones.fillColor
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n3wuLz42/
zoneAxis: 'x',
zones: [{
  value: 2,
  color: 'pink',
  fillColor: {
    linearGradient: {
      x1: 0,
      y1: 0,
      x2: 0,
      y2: 1
    },
    stops: [
      [0, "rgba(255, 105, 104, 0)"],
      [1, "rgba(255, 105, 104, 0.3)"],
    ],
  },
}]


I think that in your case you want to define the zones for yAxis and then flip them, so the colors looks like they're defined for the xAxis. If that's the case then this demo might be helpful: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nbvxfok3/

And here's your demo with flipZones function: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/89qa25z0/

thanks Dominik, but this code sets the color values ​​based on the series on the X axis, in my code this series is time, on the Y axis there are temperatures, but when I switch to the Y axis, then it is colored as in my example

You can define zones for datetime data too. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j0dL2z7f/

Dominik, I will write in Polish because we will not communicate.
W Twoim kodzie value tyczy się osi X i też z tej osi są pobierane dane dot. kolorowania wykresu. Tymczasem dane po których trzeba kolorować wykres u mnie są na osi Y!  Jak ustawię w "zoneAxis" na y to wtedy kolorowanie odbywa się poprawnie, ale poziomo, a ja chcę pionowo. Wygląda to tak:
Oś Y - temperatura
Oś X - data - czas

Then you can set the zoneAxis to y and change the values in the zones array: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j0dL2z7f/ But I'm afraid I might not know exactly what you want to achieve.

Dominik, wejdź proszę na https://jsfiddle.net/rp6b40ak/. Widzisz pokolorowany obszar areaspline?
Jest pokolorowana od lewej do prawej, chcę osiągnąć aby było to zrobione od góry do dołu. Tak jak na tej grafice: https://imgbb.com/zh5B22B
Edit: uzupełnię info, kolory zmieniają się w zależności od temperatury

You have two option in Highcharts with zones. Defining zones for xAxis: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j0dL2z7f/ and defining zones for yAxis: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4ef19zua/. I think that in your case you want to define the zones for yAxis and then flip them, so the colors looks like they're defined for the xAxis. If that's the case then this demo might be helpful: https://jsfiddle.net/8k9p66qj/3/

Thanks Dominik,
Option 3 is what I was looking for. I modified this code by adding data from a Json file that is on my server. When I import this data via data: data.temp, the chart loses the colors (it's only blue)  I set, and when I return to your example and date I give it as [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6] then it's ok. My json file is in the "temp" format:[[1712668680000,27.1],[1712668740000,27.1],[1712668800000,27.2] Would you suggest what to do to make it work properly?
Check: https://jsfiddle.net/7Lfzo3pr/

In the flipZones function we need to change the new zones value to point.x not point.index when we're using datetime data. Example demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nbvxfok3/ and your demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/89qa25z0/ I've modified my answer to include also flipZones function here.

FYI: SO is an English only website. Please refrain from using other languages
